# My numbered heading style has gone solid black, how can I fix it

Tags: microsoft-word

We use headings like this in documents:
[image]

Note that Heading 4 is not shown as 1.1.1.1 but as a black blob. This is seen when we use the style:

[image]

Headings 5 and 6 are fine, and 4 used to be when I started on the document. I have no idea how or when this happened, or how to fix it. None of the style options I can see appear to address it.

Does anyone know where this is controlled?

Comment: What version of Word are you using?

Comment: Have you checked the font color and font settings for the numbering style in the affected style?

Comment: @Mikko I've checked everything I can find!

Comment: @Mr.Boy: Would it be conceivable to replace all characters in the affected document with letters x and make the document available for inspection?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have installed any add-ons to Word, try to disable them.

Second, your Word styles might be corrupt.

Here the simplest way of resetting them:

- Close Word
- Start Explorer and position to the folder `%systemdrive%\users\%username%`
- Rename the file(s) `Normal.dot` and `Normal.dotm` so as to be able to undo
  the change (in most cases only `Normal.dotm` is present)
- Launch Word to create a new default normal template for `Normal.dotm`
- If everything works fine, you may delete the renamed files.

Note that deleting `normal.dotm` will remove all your custom settings and styles
in this default template
(if you have any).

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if custom Styles are saved in the Word file itself (#2 fix) or if its in the main template @harrymc referenced (#1 fix) so two ideas:

1. Reset template as @harrymc describes, if you open existing file & the heading is still wrong you'll need to copy & paste it to a new file where hopefully the correct heading is kept
2. Fix the heading by mimicking one of the other ones: [Modify Styles](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563)
   [image]

   A. Click working heading, modify (or copy/paste greyed out text below Preview)
    [image: ![enter image description here]

B. Click broken heading, modify & reference the working heading to modify it

**--EDIT**: Based on the link above Microsoft's wording seems to indicate Styles can be saved in JUST the Word file and/or the (default) Template so you may have to check/fix both.